# Copying template doc to active doc

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am making Office plugin to Word. Using Microsoft.Office.Interop. I have few .dotm files(Templates). When pressing a button I need to copy all text from one .dotm to my Active document. I cant figure out how can I put in variable the active document. So I can insert the info.

I tried several ways. Now I am trying to open .dotm copy text from there and then paste it to my active one. But it doesn't work. The Word will start with no errors(while starting in Visual Studio) and then when I am pressing the button it tells me that there is no open document on this: `var MyDoc = app.ActiveDocument;`

1)

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var MyDoc = app.ActiveDocument;
            var sourceDoc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\install\CSharp\test.docx");
            sourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            sourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            MyDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
```

2)

```
var newDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            newDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
            newDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\install\CSharp\test1.docx");
```

But if I do that way(2): 
It will work. But I need to paste into my active document. Also I think that the copy paste method is not so good. Maby there is some other method to import one document into an other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never, ever, ever do (2). Using `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();` is certain to cause unexpected memory leak problems. Word lets you do it, but it's not supported. `new` should only ever be used for a new instance of the Word application.

Instead, use `Documents.Add` referencing the template file. That will create a copy of the template as a new document - very simple:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var MyDoc = app.Documents.Add(@"C:\install\CSharp\test.docx");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also searching the way, how can I paste to The active document. Its VSTO Add-in. So I have the opened doc already. And I need to paste there the text what I copied. With your help I have this
var app = new Word.Application();
            var MyDoc = app.Documents.Add(@"C:\install\CSharp\test.docx");
            MyDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            MyDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

Comment: //I would like to :
var OpenedDoc = ; //something what will define my opened doc or  Word.Range rng = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0); //which is not working in Ribbon1.cs because there is no definition.
     //Then I would like to do that: OpenedDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);

Comment: @VladyZautin Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a typical "forum" - it's a Q&A repository, which means each question must be a *new* question. Could you please start a new question for what you've posted in comments? But I'm not really understanding the ***why*** of trying to copy/paste an entire document rather than using `Documents.Add` to create a copy of it. Or `InsertFile` to bring the content into another document.